# MVC calling a controller from another section and passing the model in

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a page that has a search function in a controller which works well

```
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Search(SearchModel model)
{
    ...adds to IEnumerable and such
    return View(model);
}
```

My problem is I have another page with a search box, which I need to redirect to the same view as above. (parameters in the URL is not an option)

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Home", FormMethod.Post, null))
    {
       @Html.TextBoxFor(t => t.SearchModel) 
       <input.....
    }
```

but it's not loading up the right URL, it's just adding it to the current one. so instead of example.com/Home/Search it's adding it to the end of where that form is currently located. So if the page was in example.com/About/SearchPage its adding the t.SearchModel to the About/Searchpage

Edit: I have two different Controllers and Views, ControllerA and ViewA works fine, it brings back the search results.  I want ViewB, which has an input box, to call ViewA and use ControllerA search technique

Comment: Why are you using a form inside a form?

Comment: I only have one form in my html page, I think I may have worded it wrong

Comment: @FreshJays - your example has nested forms.  You have a form tag, then you use `Html.BeginForm` which will create an additional, nested form tag in the rendered output.  View the source code in your browser and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: And what do you mean by "it's adding the t.SearchModel to the About/Searchpage"???  Do you mean as a querystring?

Comment: nevermind, mystere man you are correct about the nested form, I didn't even realize the form tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a nested form.  This is not valid HTML.  HTML does not allow you to put one form inside another form.  You can have more than one form on a page, but you cannot nest them.

I'm also not sure what you mean by "another section", do you mean the @section keyword in Razor? Or do you mean an MVC area?  Or something else?

Comment: I only have one form inside my HTML page. I have two different Controllers and Views, ControllerA and ViewA works fine, it brings back the search results.  I want ViewB, which has an input box, to call ViewA and use ControllerA search technique

Comment: @FreshJays - Do you mean you have ControllerA and ViewA and ControllerB with ViewB?  Or ControllerA with both ViewA and ViewB?

Comment: the former, I have ControllerA (which has a good search method) with ViewA and ControllerB with ViewB. I want to call ControllerA from ViewB's input button, and redirect over to ViewA as well